# How to use this QR code library (php-qrcode-detector-decoder)

Tags: php, qr-code

Please tell me step by step, I'm amateur on php.
[visit here](https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder)

How to use this code.
Please help or guide me to make this code work 100%.

```
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$qrcode = new QrReader('path/to_image');
$text = $qrcode->text(); //return decoded text from QR Code`
```

> ### QR code decoder / reader for PHP
>
> This is a PHP library to detect and decode QR-codes.
>   This is first and only QR code reader that works without extensions.
>   Ported from ZXing library
>
> ### Installation
>
> The recommended method of installing this library is via Composer.
>
> Run the following command from your project root:
>
> ```
> $ composer require khanamiryan/qrcode-detector-decoder
> ```
>
> ### Usage
>
> ```
> require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
> $qrcode = new QrReader('path/to_image');
> $text = $qrcode->text(); //return decoded text from QR Code
> ```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What errors do you get? What is *your* actual code?

Comment: i dont know this code work or not ..but i dont understand how to use this code ..because i junior programer ..please tell to me how can i do with this code

Comment: Hi, that example is really about as simple as it gets, so I'm not sure how it could be any more "step by step". Perhaps what you really need is to find a tutorial on basic PHP concepts, because if you can't follow that 3-line example, you're going to *really* struggle to put together a full program of your own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making this an answer because it is too complex for a comment.

First of all you should really try to use this code before asking for help. But let's look at the proposed code anyway:

```
<?php
// This line calls the autoload script generated by Composer. This ensures that you can
// just use the library classes without having to manually include their specific files
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
// This instantiates the QrReader class and points it to the path of a QR code image
$qrcode = new QrReader('path/to_image');
// This calls the text method on the above instance to determine the contents of the qr code
$text = $qrcode->text();
```

if this doesn't work for you then you should post the error(s) you got. If you can't see any errors then add the following right below the `<?php`

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: is it possible to read the QR code image on the fly instead of uploading?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi: Not with PHP. You'd have to look for something operating in client-side script.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble to get this working library without composer too.
The thing is it works on windows but not on linux because of the wrong capitalization of filenames and directories and such.

Then I found this blog that has a great solution:

https://www.mgcwebsites.co.uk/solved-class-zxinggdluminancesource-not-found/

> **Install a version before Composer support was added**

> Perhaps you use shared hosting that doesn’t allow you to install Composer or use SSH. Perhaps, like me, your server works perfectly and you want to keep it as clean as possible. Either way checking through the commits I was pleased to see Composer support is a fairly recent addition and that by downloading the last commit before Composer support was added I was able to forget about Composer and get the library working in seconds.

https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder/tree/cda63b7f4a8cd84d72c41b25c74284b56dc7f2cc

It works very well now...